# How to join 2 tables no foreignkey but same data's?

Tags: php

Is it possible to join to tables like in the following picture

[image]

There are no foreign key in `svotes` but there are the same records. In the select option tag I putted the `school_year` and the option are `2015-2016,2016-2017`. If I click the 2016 it should that the other table `svotes` can display the year of 2016 can it be possible? and how?

**Here's my code:**

```
<select name="sy_no" onchange="getyr(this.value)">
  <option></option>
  <?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school_year");

    while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row1['syearid'].">".$row1['from_year'].'-'.$row1['to_year']."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

**get_winner.php**

```
<?php
  include('../connect.php');
  $no = $_GET['no'];

  //this is where I get the year
  $stud = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  studentvotes,school_year WHERE school_year.from_year = studentvotes.year AND studentvotes.year = '$no' ") or die(mysql_error());
  echo"<center>";
  echo "<form action='' method='POST'  enctype='multipart/form-data' >";
  echo "  <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='dataTables-example'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>IDno</th>";
  echo "<th>Action</th>";
  echo "</tr>";

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($stud)) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studenvotes,school_year WHERE   studenvotes.year = school_year.from_year") or die(mysql_error());
    $r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<tr class="headings">
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp Take a look at joins.

Comment: Please reduce your code. The Javascript/AJAX part is completely irrelevant. Actually, the only thing that matters is probably the SQL.

Comment: what if the svotes has no foreignkey to the other table but the same records

Answer (score 1):

Try this join query

```
<select name="sy_no" onchange="getyr(this.value)">
  <option></option>
  <?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT school_year.*,svotes.* FROM school_year JOIN svotes ON , svotes.year = school_year.from_year ");

    while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        echo "<option value=".$row1['syearid'].">".$row1['from_year'].'-'.$row1['to_year']."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: when I do that there's no result will come, don't know why

Comment: i think u have connection issue

Comment: there's no records to display